# Checking parent if child checked

Tags: c#, treeview

i got this tree view and i made it to select all children if parent is checked, the way back as well. There's another rule to check some dependent child too. The problem is: I want to check the parent if any child is checked, but because those other rules i can't find a way to do that without the rules get conflict. So here's is the code i've made until now:

```
    private void tvMorgan_AfterCheck(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        //Check Children if parent checked
        if (e.Node.Nodes.Count > 0)
        {
            TreeNode tnParent = e.Node;
            if (tnParent.Checked)
            {
                foreach (TreeNode tnChild in tnParent.Nodes)
                {
                    tnChild.Checked = true;
                }
            }
            //Unchecked children if parent unchecked
            else
            {
                foreach (TreeNode tnChild in tnParent.Nodes)
                {
                    tnChild.Checked = false;
                }
            }
        }
        //If dependent node is selected, check the other two
        else if (((e.Node.Text.Contains("BRL/EUR")) && (e.Node.Checked)) && (e.Node.Parent.Text.Contains("FWD")))
        {
            TreeNode tnParent = e.Node.Parent;

            foreach (TreeNode tn in tnParent.Nodes)
            {
                if (tn.Text.Contains("BRL/USD") || tn.Text.Contains("EUR/USD"))
                    tn.Checked = true;
            }
        }
        //If one of the two necessary nodes are uncheked, then uncheck the dependent one
        else if ((((e.Node.Text.Contains("BRL/USD")) || (e.Node.Text.Contains("EUR/USD"))) && (!e.Node.Checked)) && (e.Node.Parent.Text.Contains("FWD")))
        {
            TreeNode tnParent = e.Node.Parent;

            foreach (TreeNode tn in tnParent.Nodes)
            {
                if (tn.Text.Contains("BRL/EUR"))
                    tn.Checked = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Would be much better if you could provide a cut down version of your code which isolates the problem.  In lieu of that I will mention that you probably want to disable the event handler AfterCheck at the beginning of your method and re-enable it at the end.  This will disable the recursive aspect of your current method.

Comment: also, i would separate the logic of the parent-child auto selection (as per the question) from the more hard coded rules with text contains

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of the [TreeView.AfterCheck Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.aftercheck.aspx) shows exactly how to do what you are looking for